# Unit Test - No Code Coverage with Wrapper Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Having issues getting any code coverage, no lines have been covered yet i am returning the data to the test method that I want and the System Assert is running as anticipated

**Class to Be Tested**

```
public with sharing class UserProfile {

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static wrapperToLWC getUserData() {

    List <Id> cdId = new List <Id>(); 

    //Retrieve Account Id attached the current Community User
    User currentUser = [SELECT Contact.AccountId FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];

    Account currentUserAccount = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :currentUser.Contact.AccountId LIMIT 1];

    User billingUser = [SELECT FullPhotoUrl, SmallPhotoUrl FROM User WHERE ContactId = :currentUserAccount.Primary_Billing_Contact__r.Id LIMIT 1];

    //Wrap everything in a wrapper object to pass to Lightning Web Component
    return new wrapperToLWC(currentUserAccount, billingUser);
}

    public class wrapperToLWC {
       @AuraEnabled public User objUser;
       @AuraEnabled public Account objAcc;

       public wrapperToLWC (Account acc, User use) {
        this.objAcc = acc;
        this.objUser = use;
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@isTest
public with sharing class UserProfileTest {

    @isTest
    static void dataCreator() {
        // Insert a User
        // Insert an Account with an attachment to current User

        Account testAccount = new Account();

            testAccount.Name = 'Joe sampTester';

        insert testAccount;

            Contact testContact = new Contact();
                testContact.FirstName = 'Joe';
                testContact.LastName = 'Tester';
                testContact.AccountId = testAccount.Id;
                testContact.Email = 'test123@test.com';

            insert testContact;

                Profile profileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User' LIMIT 1];

                User testUser = new User();

                    testUser.LastName = 'Tester';
                    testUser.Email = 'test@test.com';
                    testUser.Alias = 'Tcode';
                    testUser.Username = 'test123@test.com';
                    testUser.CommunityNickname = 'test12';
                    testUser.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
                    testUser.TimeZoneSidKey = 'GMT';
                    testUser.ProfileID = profileId.Id;
                    testUser.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
                    testUser.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
                    testUser.ContactId = testContact.Id;

                    insert testUser;

                    system.runAs(testUser) {

                        Test.startTest();
                        UserProfile.wrapperToLWC testWrapper = UserProfile.getUserData();
                        Test.stopTest();

                        System.debug(testWrapper);

                        System.assertEquals('Joe sampTester', testWrapper.objAcc.Name);

                    }

    }
}
```

I am at a bit of a loss, is it the wrapper class causing the issue or maybe system.RunAs? any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Hey try granting UserProfile : class access to "Standard User" profile

Comment: @AbhijithE It is returning data correctly (so its not a permissions issue). it is just not producing code coverage

Comment: Please don't post the same [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/298432/code-coverage-on-method-that-calls-and-returns-wrapper-class) more than once.

Comment: Does your test pass? It seems like the only way it could fail to cover that method is if the method itself failed.

Comment: Yes, test passes. However it still says 0/19 lines covered